# How to load controller in Angular 1.6 (Argument 'simpleController' is not a function, got undefined)

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, single-page-application

I am trying to learn AngularJS, I have `View1` which uses `simpleController`, but AngularJS (1.6) is throwing an error and I can't find the right syntax to make it work.

My Repository is: https://github.com/tommcclean/Learning_Angular.

> Error: ng:areq. Bad Argument. Argument 'simpleController' is not a
>   function, got undefined

**`View1` contains...**

```
<div ng-controller="simpleController as ctrl">
    <h2>View One</h2>

    <p>{{ ctrl.testValue }}</p>
</div>
```

**`simpleController` contains...**

```
"use strict";

(function () {
    angular.module('demoApp').controller('simpleController', []);

    function simpleController() {
        var self = this;

        self.testValue = "Test Value";

        self.updateValue = function () {
            self.testValue = "Test Value Updated";
        };

        return self;
    };
});
```

**`demoApp` is created by my routes.js file which is loaded first.**

```
"use strict";

var app = angular.module('demoApp', ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/view1',
        {
            controller: 'simpleController',
            templateUrl: '../views/view1.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });
});
```

**My main page which is the home of my "spa" contains...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sample Demo Application</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body ng-app="demoApp" class="container">
    <h1>Welcome to my Sample Application</h1>

    <a href="#!view1">View 1</a>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../app/initialise/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="../app/controllers/simpleController.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the .controller definition should have the function not an empty array as the second argument.

```
"use strict";

(function () {
    angular.module('demoApp').controller('simpleController', simpleController);

    function simpleController() {
        var self = this;

        self.testValue = "Test Value";

        self.updateValue = function () {
            self.testValue = "Test Value Updated";
        };

        return self;
    };
});
```

```js
"use strict";

var app = angular.module('demoApp', ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/view1',
        {
            controller: 'simpleController',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            templateUrl: '/view1.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });
});

(function () {
    function simpleController() {
        var self = this;

        self.testValue = "Test Value";

        self.updateValue = function () {
            self.testValue = "Test Value Updated";
        };

        return self;
    };
    angular.module('demoApp').controller('simpleController', simpleController);

})();
```

```html
<body ng-app="demoApp" class="container">
    <h1>Welcome to my Sample Application</h1>

    <a href="#!view1">View 1</a>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/view1.html">
  
<div>
    <h2>View One</h2>

    <p>{{ ctrl.testValue }}</p>
</div>
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Shaun, that seems to have resolved that error, but I now get the error "Error: $controller:ctrlreg. A controller with this name is not registered. The controller with the name 'simpleController' is not registered." Is that a result of that change, or something else I have done incorrectly?

Comment: Hmm not sure off hand that error is a bit unfamiliar.  Will try to paste your code into a running sample here.

Comment: @TomMcClean got it so a couple of things, the ng-controller was't necessary just need controllerAs in the route definition, other thing was the IIFE wasn't being invoked so added () at the end of that and fixed it.

Comment: Also, thanks much for providing the full context for the problem and not making it huge, much appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks for spending time helping with this Shaun, its a great help and I can now get it to run with your advice! :)